# android: menu won't show up

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-fragments

I'm trying to have a different menu show up when a fullscreen dialog is shown but it won't appear. Instead, a blank menu appears.

I've tried calling it conditionally from the original activity and I've tried calling it from the dialog view.

Here's the fullscreen Dialog View:

```
public class MyMainView extends DialogFragment {
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setStyle(DialogFragment.STYLE_NORMAL, R.layout.layout_full_screen_dialog);
        setHasOptionsMenu(true);
    }

    @Override public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater) {
        menu.clear();
        new MenuInflater(this.getActivity()).inflate(R.menu.add_to_user_library, menu);
        //inflater.inflate(R.menu.add_to_user_library, menu);
        super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu, inflater);
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreateView(inflater, container, savedInstanceState);
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.add_to_user_library, container, false);
        // view code here

        return view;
    }
}
```

*Menu XML*:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    tools:context=".result.ResultActivity">

    <item
        android:id="@+id/save"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_check"
        android:showAsAction="ifRoom"
        android:title="@string/menu_save_library"
        tools:ignore="AppCompatResource" />

    <item
        android:id="@+id/go_back"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_clear"
        android:showAsAction="ifRoom"
        android:title="@string/menu_save_library"
        tools:ignore="AppCompatResource" />
</menu>
```

From the activity

```
public final class ResultActivity extends CoreActivity {

    public static void startActivityForResult(Activity a, Result r, int requestCode) {
        Intent i = new Intent(a, ResultActivity.class);
        i.putExtra(EXTRA_RESULT, r);
        a.startActivityForResult(i, requestCode);
        a.overridePendingTransition(R.anim.slide_from_right, R.anim.slide_to_left);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        new MenuInflater(this).inflate(R.menu.activity_result, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case R.id.case1:
            {
                Bundle b = new Bundle();

                String myString = (String.valueOf(_result.myString));
                b.putString("myString", myString);
                SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat(DATE_FORMAT, Locale.US);
                String timeStamp = sdf.format(new Date(_result._timestamp));
                b.putString("timeStamp", timeStamp);
                String myString1 = _result.myString1;
                b.putString("myString1", myString1);
                //show the dialog
                DialogFragment newFragment = new MyMainView();
                newFragment.setArguments(b);
                newFragment.show(getFragmentManager(),"SaveIt");
                return true;
            }
            case case2:
            {
                //etc...
```

Right now, when the dialog shows up but the menu appears right before it loads then becomes blank.

What I see is the following.

[image]